# How to do operations on list columns in an R data.table to output another list column?

Tags: r, data.table

I still have a difficult time thinking about how one works with R data.table columns which are lists.

Here is an R data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(
      numericcol = rep(42, 8),
      listcol = list(c(1, 22, 3), 6, 1, 12, c(5, 6, 1123), 3, 42, 1)
  )
> dt
   numericcol        listcol
1:         42        1,22, 3
2:         42              6
3:         42              1
4:         42             12
5:         42    5,   6,1123
6:         42              3
7:         42             42
8:         42              1
```

I would like to create a column for the absolute values between the elements of `numericcol` and `listcol`:

```
> dt
   numericcol        listcol    absvals 
1:         42        1,22, 3    41, 20, 39
2:         42              6    36
3:         42              1    41
4:         42             12    30
5:         42    5,   6,1123    37, 36, 1081
6:         42              3    39
7:         42             42    0
8:         42              1    41
```

So, my first thought would be to use `sapply()` as follows:

```
dt[, absvals := sapply(listcol, function(x) abs(x-numericcol))]
```

This outputs the following:

```
> dt
   numericcol        listcol absvals
1:         42        1,22, 3      41
2:         42              6      20
3:         42              1      39
4:         42             12      41
5:         42    5,   6,1123      20
6:         42              3      39
7:         42             42      41
8:         42              1      20
```

So, `absvals` is now a column of unlisted elements, with an individual element in each row, and is a different dimension than the data.table.

(1) How would one create `absvals` to retain the list structure of `listcol`?

(2) In cases like these, if I am only interested in a vector of the values, how do R data.table users create such a data structure?

Maybe

```
vec = as.vector(dt[, absvals := sapply(listcol, function(x) abs(x-numericcol))])
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another solution using `mapply`:

```
dt[, absvals := mapply(listcol, numericcol, FUN = function(x, y) abs(x-y))]

#output
dt
   numericcol        listcol        absvals
1:         42        1,22, 3       41,20,39
2:         42              6             36
3:         42              1             41
4:         42             12             30
5:         42    5,   6,1123   37,  36,1081
6:         42              3             39
7:         42             42              0
8:         42              1             41
```

Comment: superior answer. very nice

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally a row-wise operation, I think, so the approach is bound to be a bit wonky. And the key to remember with `list` columns in `data.table` is that `[.data.table` assumes any output of `j` which is a `list` refers to columns -- so you need to wrap any `list` in `list` again to make `j` understand there's only one column.

I think this works for your case:

```
dt[ , abs_vals := list(lapply(seq_along(.I), function(ii) 
  abs(listcol[[ii]] - numericcol[ii])))][]
#    numericcol        listcol       abs_vals
# 1:         42        1,22, 3       41,20,39
# 2:         42              6             36
# 3:         42              1             41
# 4:         42             12             30
# 5:         42    5,   6,1123   37,  36,1081
# 6:         42              3             39
# 7:         42             42              0
# 8:         42              1             41
```

The `seq_along(.I)` part is handling the row-wise aspect.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you really do not need list column?
It looks like you could do all of this simpler.

```
# convert to long format:
dt2 <- dt[, .(var = unlist(listcol)), by = numericcol]
dt2[, absval := abs(var - numericcol)]
dt2
    numericcol  var absval
 1:         42    1     41
 2:         42   22     20
 3:         42    3     39
 4:         42    6     36
 5:         42    1     41
 6:         42   12     30
 7:         42    5     37
 8:         42    6     36
 9:         42 1123   1081
10:         42    3     39
11:         42   42      0
12:         42    1     41
```

In my experience it is harder and much slower to work with list objects than simple data.tables.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map`

```
dt[, absvals := Map(function(x, y) abs(x-y), listcol, numericcol)]
dt
#    numericcol        listcol        absvals
#1:         42        1,22, 3       41,20,39
#2:         42              6             36
#3:         42              1             41
#4:         42             12             30
#5:         42    5,   6,1123   37,  36,1081
#6:         42              3             39
#7:         42             42              0
#8:         42              1             41
```

---

Or with `purrr::map`

```
dt[, absvals := map2(listcol, numericcol, ~ abs(.x -.y))]
```

---

Instead of looping many times, there is also an option to `unlist` and get the absolute difference from the `rep`licated 'numericol' based on the `lengths` of 'listvals'.  It could be more efficient

```
dt[, absvals := relist(abs(rep(numericcol, lengths(listcol)) - 
                   unlist(listcol)), skeleton = listcol)]
```

NOTE: Here, there is no need to replicate as it is the same value for 'numericol', but the `rep` is for general case

Answer (score 2):

You could use `apply()` to go through your `data.table` row by row and get the absolute value of the difference of `numericol` and each element of `listcol` like this;

```
dt[, absvals := apply(.SD, 
                      1, 
                      function(x) abs(x$numericcol - x$listcol))]
```

The output is this:

```
   numericcol        listcol        absvals
1:         42        1,22, 3       41,20,39
2:         42              6             36
3:         42              1             41
4:         42             12             30
5:         42    5,   6,1123   37,  36,1081
6:         42              3             39
7:         42             42              0
8:         42              1             41
```